# Related to colors in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to change a button color in my app by selecting color. Instead of setting the color as static, I want user to choose the color like this [image]

or any API to use for objective c. Can anyone guide me how to proceed?

Comment: do You want to change the button's color or should the user be able to change it?

Comment: use customImagePicker and u will get color refernce and set in btn's backgroundColor as btn will be custom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at how the code works in these classes from this open source project you should be able to integrate it into your view.

http://maniacdev.com/2011/11/open-source-ios-color-picker-components-roundup/

Hope this helps!

Sam